# Variable interpolation in ASP, ADO

Tags: html, asp-classic, ado

I am using a variable to interpolate in ASP, for this i have an vairable:

```
cid=Request.Form("customerID")
```

and then,

```
rs.open "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID='" & cid & "'",conn
```

the above statement does not work.
while this works:

```
rs.open "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID=1",conn
```

can someone please help me???

Comment: That should work if `cid` is `1`, have you verified? That is vulnerable to sql injection. What is its failure mode?

Comment: A simple way of protecting that snippet against an injection attack would be `cid=Cint(Request.Form("customerID"))` - assuming that customerID is a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you code is wide open for a SQL injection!!!

read about parametrized queries.

in your first SQL you have apostrophes (') which is bad if cid is a number

Comment: Thanks @ulluoink :), removing (') worked for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user3275206 I wouldn't recommend you use this this method in a production environment look at using `ADODB.Command` instead to build parameterised queries.